# VBA writes to first Excel cell only, not second

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a form to process data and write it into a worksheet.  The form is working but whenever I write to a cell, the first data is written and then the subroutine exits without error.

I have written some test code; "aaa" is written but "bbb" is not.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DJ").Cells(10, 1) = "aaa"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DJ").Cells(10, 2) = "bbb"
    
    
    Exit Sub ' Exit to avoid handler.

ErrorHandler: ' Error-handling routine.

    Dim E As Integer
    E = Err.Number
    
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out the error handler and rerun it to see if you get an error. Then debug based on the error message. I'm wondering if `.Cell(10, 2)` is locked on a protected sheet.

Comment: OR put `Msgbox Err.Description` in `ErrorHandler:`

Comment: The sheet is not protected.   I put a message box in the error handler but nothing happens.  When I step through the routine, it exits immediately after the first write - it does not get to the second write.  (Cannot understand why something so simple is not working!!)

Comment: After the line `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DJ").Cells(10, 2) = "bbb"` put `Msgbox ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DJ").Cells(10, 2).Value` What do you get? Also check if the font color of that cell is not set to white

Comment: Font colour not white.  I have updated the code to put a MsgBox before and after  the first write; first MsgBox appears, second does not!  When stepping, does not get to the second MsgBox - just aborts.

MsgBox (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DJ").Cells(10, 1).Value)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DJ").Cells(10, 1) = "aaa"
MsgBox (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DJ").Cells(10, 1).Value)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DJ").Cells(10, 2) = "bbb"

Comment: I have created a brand-new workbook, new form and test code - now working.  I'll start putting the rest of the code back in...

Comment: Working fine now.  The original workbook must have been corrupted - I got some errors trying to load Outlook date controls, which I could then not delete.  All very strange, but my project is making good progress now - thanks to those who took the time to reply.